# how can I debug the shape placement in the Orchard CMS admin screens

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I had arranged shapes in the placement file, and they were not placed correctly. I want to debug the shapes placement, I enabled the shape tracing module, but the shape tracing tools is not showing in the admin screens.

I wonder how can I show the shape tracing bar in the admin screens, or how can I debug the shape placement in the admin screens?

Comment: Shape tracing doesn't work in the admin section, what problem are you having with your placement?

Comment: Yes Indeed. Actually my problem is that after I configured the placement files, the content didn't appeared, I wanted to debug the shape placement to figure out what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in using Shape Tracer on admin pages, open up the ShapeTracingFactory.cs file in Orchard.DesignerTools module, and comment out the following line in the IsActivable method:

if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(new RequestContext(_workContext.HttpContext, new RouteData())))
     return false;

Comment: Did not work for me. I cannot see the small toolbar for the shape tracing.

Comment: Apply this also in the TemplatesFilter.cs and it works! very handy for admin alternates :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, you can change the placement in the Admin Area. 
Just go to "Content Definitions", look for the "Content Type", edit it and there is a placement button top right "Edit Placement". 
That will work for the Editors, if what you are looking for is the placements within the lists; 
You must do that from the placement file itself. You can match the "Display Type", SummaryAdmin for example to hide elements. That is if those are you Customs types or Common Types. 
If what you are trying to "place" comes from another module, you must change the placement in that very module.

Comment: I'm not asking about "How to do the placement". My question is about how to debug the placement.